# Unpermitted parameter: file rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application i am creating a form which uploads multiple document. Now i have posted the form with 2 upload documents but not able to save in the database due to the error. But I am getting all the parameters as mentioned above. Please help me out to solve this issue.

In controller:

```
def create
  @sr_document = SrDocument.new(sr_document_params)
end

def sr_document_params
  params.require(:sr_document).permit(:file_type, :file, :service_request_id, :file_file_name, :file_content_type, :file_file_size)
end
```

In log:

> "sr_document"=>{"file"=>[
>
> @tempfile=#,
>   @original_filename="Reliance Web-Chat.pdf",
>   @content_type="application/pdf", @headers="Content-Disposition:
>   form-data; name=\"sr_document[file][]\"; filename=\"Reliance
>   Web-Chat.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">,
>
> @tempfile=#\, @original_filename="Flipkart.pdf", @content_type="application/pdf",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"sr_document[file][]\"; filename=\"Flipkart.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/pdf\r\n">
>
> ]}

Comment: Unpermitted parameter: file

Comment: `file` is a field in  `sr_documents` table? can you show us the `form`?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting array of file, so that I think you are getting issue:
Try to permit your file attribute as:

```
def sr_document_params
  params.require(:sr_document).permit(:file_type, :file => [], :service_request_id, :file_file_name, :file_content_type, :file_file_size)
end
```

Comment: syntax error in : params.require(:sr_document).permit(file: [])

Comment: Try to do this " params.require(:sr_document).permit! "

Comment: Array and hash parameters must be at the end, after `:service_request_id, :file_file_name,...`, although it looks like those other parameters aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

These files are stored in an array and the file's information like `file_content_type`,.. are attributes of each file, so you can't get it like this.
Please try:

```
def create
  sr_documents = []
  sr_document_params[:file].each do |file|
     sr_documents << SrDocument.new({ file_content_type: file.content_type, 
                                      file_size: file.size,
                                      file: file })
  end
end


def sr_document_params
  params.require(:sr_document).permit(file: [])
end
```

Comment: syntax error in : params.require(:sr_document).permit(file: [])